# Type does not contain a definition for IsAssignableFrom

Tags: c#, .net-standard

As per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) piece of documentation, I am trying to use the `IsAssignableFrom` method. However, I get the following exception:

> Error   CS1061  'Type' does not contain a definition for 'IsAssignableFrom' and no extension method 'IsAssignableFrom' accepting a first argument of type 'Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The offending line is

`if (!desiredType.IsAssignableFrom(outputType))`

in the following class:

```
internal class DefaultResolvable : IResolvable
{
    internal IDictionary<Type, Type> TypeContainer { get; set; }

    public T Resolve<T>()
    {
        if(this.TypeContainer == null)
        {
            throw new TypeRepositoryEmptyException();
        }

        var desiredType = typeof(T);
        var outputPair = this.TypeContainer.FirstOrDefault(pair => pair.Key == desiredType);
        if(outputPair.Key == null || outputPair.Value == null)
        {
            throw new CannotResolveTypeException();
        }

        var outputType = outputPair.Value;
        if (!desiredType.IsAssignableFrom(outputType))
        {
            throw new CannotResolveTypeException();
        }

        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(outputType);
    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing here? Why am I getting this exception?

Comment: Targeting .NET COre by any chance?

Comment: Are you using .Net core?

Comment: Targeting .Net Standard 1.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .Net Standard or .Net Core you should call `GetTypeInfo()`:

```
if (!desiredType.GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(outputType))
```

Comment: Cheers, didn't know I had to do it that way in Standard!

Comment: Great, just had to add `System.Reflection` namespace.